# Issues with stopping a variable playing

Tags: python

I haven't been coding very long (less then 3 weeks), and I wanted to test around and experiment a text-based game. I probably did this poorly, but when confronted with a decision I tried to nest another decision within the first decision. But then when I tried to do option B of decision 1, it would try and run a decision nested under option A of decision 1, which caused problems. I'll show you what I mean:

```
kill1 = input("Attack old man? (y/n) ")
if kill1 == "y":
print("You strike the old man with all your force")
time.sleep(1)
print("Old Man staggers back, his right arm crippled")
else:
print("Thanks for the staff")

if kill1 == "y":
kill2 = input("Strike again or run away? (s/r) ")
if kill2 == "s":
print("You swing the staff into the mans ribs")
time.sleep(1)
print("The man falls to the ground, incapacitiated")
else:
print("You run away into the woods")
```

Output/error:

```
Attack old man? (y/n) n
Thanks for the staff  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/game.py", line 28, in <module>
    if kill2 == "s":
NameError: name 'kill2' is not defined
```

Sorry if this is poorly formatted, I'm quiet new and the text options confused me.

Comment: Please fix the formatting so that the indentation matches your real code. The indentation is significant in Python (unlike many other languages), not just a convention, so it's very important for us to know exactly what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
if kill1 == "y":
    kill2 = input("Strike again or run away? (s/r) ")
if kill2 == "s":
    print("You swing the staff into the mans ribs")
```

If `kill1` is not `"y"`, then the variable `kill2` never gets assigned a value.

It looks like you should indent your code so that the `if kill2 == "s"` test is inside the `if kill1 == "y"` block, like this:

```
if kill1 == "y":
    kill2 = input("Strike again or run away? (s/r) ")
    if kill2 == "s":
        print("You swing the staff into the mans ribs")
```